# Regex - Match sets of words

Tags: javascript, regex

In JavaScript, how would I get `['John Smith', 'Jane Doe']` from `"John Smith - Jane Doe"` where `-` can be any separator (`\ / , + * : ;`) and so on, using regex ?
Using `new RegExp('[a-zA-Z]+[^\/|\-|\*|\+]', 'g')` will just give me `["John ", "Smith ", "Jane ", "Doe"]`

Comment: Do you always will have two words?

Comment: If you're going to down vote, then please leave a comment as to why you've done so

Comment: That is the issue, it may not be limited to two words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, no regex:

```
var arr = str.split(' - ')
```

**Edit**

Multiple separators:

```
var arr = str.split(/ [-*+,] /)
```

Comment: Not my dv, but the OP specifically said *"...where `-` can be any separator (`\` `/` `,` `+` `*` `:` `;`) and so on..."*, so this isn't a useful answer.

Comment: `-` can be replaced with anything.

Comment: Well, my read is that the OP doesn't know what the delimiters will be in the string, just that they *may* be any of various characters, and so needs to handle a broad range. This approach would require a couple of dozen `split` calls, at least, to achieve that.

Comment: Gets an upvote from me, anyway. As I said in my answer, I think the OP is better off defining the separators rather than the characters that can be in the names, so "Elizabeth Peña" or "Gerard 't Hooft" work. :-) That's what your second example above does.

Comment: I like this. @T.J.Crowder - the edit takes care of defining my delimiters up front, and this matches the whole name out of the box, so I'll go with this

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match multiple words, you need to have a space in your character class. I'd think something like `/[ a-zA-Z]+/g` would be a starting point, used repeatedly with `exec` or via `String#match`, like this: [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ugurof) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ugurof/edit)

```
var str = "John Smith - Jane Doe";
var index;
var matches = str.match(/[ a-zA-Z]+/g);
if (matches) {
  display("Found " + matches.length + ":");
  for (index = 0; index < matches.length; ++index) {
    display("[" + index + "]: " + matches[index]);
  }
}
else {
  display("No matches found");
}
```

But it's **very** limited, a huge number of names have characters other than A-Z, you may want to invert your logic and use a negated class (`/[^...]/g`, where `...` is a list of possible delimiter characters). You don't want to leave "Elizabeth Peña" or "Gerard 't Hooft" out in the cold! :-)